# AWS Athena Cast Works in Select Statement but Fails with Where Clause

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a very simple query:

```
select cast(Field1 as bigint) as lit
from vw_GH
```

That works like a charm. However, when I add a where clause like so:

```
select cast(Field1 as bigint) as lit
from vw_GH
where Field2 > SomeNumber
```

It gives me an INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT error. Since this is a big data task it's not quick to identify potential errors in a set of millions of records. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like there is a record in vw_GH where Field1 has a value that cannot be converted to bigint. Ex. If Field1 has a value of "TEXT" then it cannot be converted to a bigint.

Comment: @NiharikaBitra That makes sense, but if that's the case why would it work when there's not a where clause?

Comment: Good point! So it seems like the issue is with Field2 then. If Field2 is not an actual number, we cannot determine if its larger than someNumber. Is Field2 an integer?

Comment: If Field2 is not an interger, then behind the scenes, it gets casted into an integer.

Comment: "If Field2 is not an interger, then behind the scenes, it gets casted into an integer." -- i wouldn't expect this to happen. Definitely not in Presto, unless Athena adds some custom coercion rules.